# Show f is Continuous- path connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

[image]

I have seen a proof involving technique beyond my course, I wanted to see anyone knows of any "elementary way" of proving this with just definitions of a set being closed, bounded and path-connected.

Comment: Could you sketch the proof you've seen, so that we see what you mean by not/more elementary?

Comment: I suppose that the proof that you have seen involve Frechet points,right?

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227391/function-which-preserves-closed-boundedness-and-path-connectedness-continuous

Comment: @julien dimitries is right to say frechet points where involved which is something I haven't learnt yet all. What i mean by elementary is purely from the defintions of a set being closed (sequence defn), bounded (in terms of a metric) and path connected (cts function between any two points in the set), I'm quite limited it what I know so I'm not so sure I have the tools to do this question

Comment: @AndrewD thanks

Comment: Then I guess the answer on the link provided by Andrew D fits the bill. And that  makes your question a duplicate.